# terraform - load json file from external source (S3) and inject variables into it

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

Consider this:

```
// fruits.json
{ 
   "fruits" : 
      {
          "apples": 3,
          "bananas": 4,
          "pears": "${pears}"
      }
}
```

In terraform I can do this:

```
# main.tf

variable "pears" {
    type    = number
    default = 2
}


locals { 
      fruits = templatefile("fruits.json", { pears = "${var.pears}" })
}
```

However, I want to put that json file on S3. I can fetch its content like this:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "fruits" {
    bucket = "fruits"
    key    = "subdir/fruits.json"
}

locals {    
    data = jsondecode(data.aws_s3_bucket_object.fruits.body)  
}
```

But then I'm not actually injecting my variable like when using `templatefile`. It just fetches it as a literal string `{pears}` (replacing it with a direct `{var.pears}` doesn't work either).

How do I work around this? Seems like terraform doesn't have a built in "parsing" functionality I can just manually call. templatefile doesn't accept strings and the old data source that could transform a string to an IO file object was deprecated. It's unclear to me whether what I'm asking for is even possible.

Comment: Does the file in S3 have to be a valid JSON, i.e., can you leave it with a template variable?

Comment: @MarkoE honestly it doesn't have to be a valid JSON, but I don't know how that changes anything. I can inject variables to a local file I'm loading through `templatefile`. I can't easily do the same to a string loaded from a file on S3, or can I?

Comment: Hm, have you considered using the `local_file` resource maybe? And pass it the output of the data source?

Comment: @MarkoE so use `local_file` to create the file locally then re-load it with templatefile? Does that work? Seems incredibly convoluted but if that works it's an option

Comment: Just tested it, didn't work out. You can't read a local file that's created by a different resource apparently (makes sense honestly)

Comment: @yuvi, just so I understand: You read a json from s3, which has the variable in it, you have a variable that you want to interpolate then you want to upload it in a different object/bucket with the interpolation applied?

Comment: @AndreiSfat Sort of. Our use case is we have different environments (multiple production env, staging, etc.). These envs each have a bunch of spot instances with the same structure but different values. It's very tedious to make every part of these a terraform variable, it's much more sensible to have these configurations described in a json file on S3, and we need to inject some variables into that file. Basically we just want to run `templatefile()` but keep the json file saved on the cloud and not locally. Feels like it should be simple to do

Comment: doesn't https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file help ? it's pretty much the same as `templatefile`, but it's a data source and you take the result with `.rendered`. I wanted to answer to the question, but wasn't sure what exactly you wanted

Comment: nvm, just read that `templatefile` is the recommended way

Comment: unless you want to go the deprecated path to use `template_file`, seems that `templatefile` does not work with remote files unless you have the template file locally in your code (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/30616). I also tried `local_file` but doesn't work, unfortunately. Sorry for not being more helpful :(

Comment: yeah I tried all of that. you can't use `local_file` to create a file and then read from it, it doesn't make sense either. Feels like terraform should just let us manually call the string parser but whatever even if it's a security risk